# SQL query to find row with no immediate successor

Tags: sql, select

I have an sql query that returns me the following result:

```
 select id, position from (...)

 aaa   6
 aab   5
 aac   3
 aad   2
```

So I need the first row with no immediate successor. Here is an illustration:

- First row is `6` next is `5` so it has a successor `6 -> 5`
- Second row is `5` next is `3` so it has no successor, because `4` is missing

So in this example the outer select should return `aab 5`

Comment: What do you mean by "the first row with no predecessor"? `aab 5` is the second row and it *has* a predecessor.

Comment: What is with the last row? `2` has also no predecessor. And is the predecessor only based on `position`?

Comment: No just the first it finds

Comment: @wasp256 means successor, not predecessor. Edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a query that I believe does what you are asking. It joins the table on itself with the position - 1. Then get the ones that are null.

```
select a.* from test1 a
left join test1 b on a.position - 1 = b.position
where b.position is null
```

This returns

```
aab 5
aad 2
```